# delete pictures from slides in powerpoint from excel

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I tried to figured out why the coding is not working, but the following code was supposed to open from excel a powerpoint and clear the existing slides in order to replace with new picture - however I'm getting the following:

> error 91: Object variable or with block variable not set.

I tried several others code from the Stack but cannot make it work.. any help please? The deck contains slide 2 to slide 9 to cleared out.

```
Sub ppt_export()
Dim DestinationPPT As String
Dim ppApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim ppPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim objApp As Object, objSlide As Object, ObjShp As Object, objTable As` Object

DestinationPPT = "C:\Users\\Desktop\Summary.pptx"
Set ppApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Open(DestinationPPT)
'delete the shapes from the renew the template

 For i = ppSlide.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
Set ppShape = ppSlide.Shapes(p)
If ppShape.Type = msoPicture Then ppShape.Delete
Next
End Sub
```

I'd like to know how to correct the code in order to continue the coding with copying excel worksheets as pictures into the respective slide.

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module and it would make your problem apparent. The `For` statement uses `i`, but then you attempt to use `p` inside the loop.

Comment: @BigBen thank you, I switched the `p` to the `i` but it loop to the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*First and most importantly*, add `Option Explicit` to the top of the code module, and it will flag the various undeclared variables you have: `p`, `i`, `ppSlide`, and `ppShape`.

Then the code might look something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExportToPPT()
    Dim ppApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Set ppApp = New PowerPoint.Application

    Dim ppFileName As String
    ppFileName = "C:\Users\\Desktop\Summary.pptx"

    Dim ppPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Open(Filename:=ppFileName)

    Dim ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 2 To 9
        Set ppSlide = ppPres.Slides(i)

        Dim j As Integer
        For j = ppSlide.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
            If ppSlide.Shapes(j).Type = msoPicture Then
                ppSlide.Shapes(j).Delete
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: would you know as well why I would have a Object variable or with block variable not set when I do the following continuation in the code `Dim lRow, lCol As Integer` and with the following `Sheets("Waterfall").Select
    lRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lCol = cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`

Comment: What line throws the error? By the way, `Long` is preferable to `Integer`; you can change to `Dim lRow as Long, lCol as Long`.

Comment: Thanks, I changed them for `as Long` - the line in error is `lCol = cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`

Comment: What I expected. Do you have a variable named `cells`?

Comment: If better to see the whole code, I can edit the one above as it is a direct continuation from the one you helped with - the aim is to clear out the existing slides, then copy paste from excel to ppt as a picture the new inputs.

Comment: I have a `Dim cells As Excel.Range`

Comment: Get rid of that.

Comment: ok but then this line end up with variable not defined for "cell" :-)
`For Each cell In Range(cells(1, "D"), cells(1, lCol))
 Union(Range("D1:AE" & lRow), Range(cells(1, cells.Column), cells(lRow, cells.Column))).CopyPicture`

Comment: Maybe you should ask this as a new question. In any case, `cells` is a confusing variable name, since [`Range.Cells`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.cells) already exists. `cell` (singular) is ok.