# recommendation on coding for a multiple copy paste functions : create a new module for each or all into one code?

Tags: excel, vba

Happy Sunday everyone.
I need some advice on what would be the best approach to continue a code - my worry is to keep it smooth and simple somehow (the file is a 20MB file).
I have the below coding ([thanks @BigBen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55427908/5223757)). It copy paste a game of products (x8) from one worksheet into a ppt after refresh. 
I could reproduce the same logic to Sheet "B" from range "C1:AE37"

Do you recommend to use a new module for each sheet?  - or can I upgrade the coding below with like a text box asking what to export (Select Sheet A, Sheet B, etc..) and loop the `if` back to each copy-paste sheets range to a ppt slide? which ones are more efficient to keep the Excel smooth? 
many thanks in advance for the help.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ExportToPPT()

Dim ppApp As PowerPoint.Application
Set ppApp = New PowerPoint.Application

Dim ppFileName As String
ppFileName = "C:\Users\\Desktop\Financial Summary.pptx"

Dim ppPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Open(filename:=ppFileName)

Dim ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

Dim i As Integer
For i = 2 To 9
    Set ppSlide = ppPres.Slides(i)

    Dim j As Integer
    For j = ppSlide.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
        If ppSlide.Shapes(j).Type = msoPicture Then
            ppSlide.Shapes(j).Delete
        End If
    Next j
Next i

Dim Sel As Range
Dim source As Range
Dim l As Long

For l = 8 To 1 Step -1
Workbooks("WWDWT.xlsm").Sheets("Graph Data").Range("E4").Value = l
Application.Calculate

Set source = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("A").Range("D1")
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("A").Range("D1:AF40").Copy

Set ppSlide = ppPres.Slides(l + 1)
ppSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteBitmap
Next l
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just parametrise all of the things, like so:

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub ExportToPPT(ppFileName As String, xlFileName as String, xlCalculationSheetName as String, xlDataSheetName)

Dim ppApp As PowerPoint.Application
Set ppApp = New PowerPoint.Application

Dim ppPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Open(filename:=ppFileName)

Dim ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

Dim i As Integer
For i = 2 To 9
    Set ppSlide = ppPres.Slides(i)

    Dim j As Integer
    For j = ppSlide.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
        If ppSlide.Shapes(j).Type = msoPicture Then
            ppSlide.Shapes(j).Delete
        End If
    Next j
Next i

Dim Sel As Range
Dim source As Range
Dim l As Long

For l = 8 To 1 Step -1
Workbooks(xlFileName).Sheets(xlCalculationSheetName).Range("E4").Value = l
Application.Calculate

Set source = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(xlCalculationSheetName).Range("D1")
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(xlCalculationSheetName).Range("D1:AF40").Copy

Set ppSlide = ppPres.Slides(l + 1)
ppSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteBitmap
Next l
End Sub
```

Parametrise more of the things as necessary.

Comment: Thanks @wizzwizz4 I will try to pull it as a test to see if I can, but if I want to attach the vba into a toolbox, how would the function decide whether it is sheets "A" or sheets "B" I want to export?

Comment: @Guillaume I don't understand. Please explain better what your code _means_.

Comment: the code does currently open a sheet, open a powerpoint, clear out all the slides from the powerpoint, then the loop start for each product, copy the range from sheets "A" to paste it as a picture into a slide.
Now what I would like to achieve is take the option on decide whether I want to copy Sheets "A" or Sheets "B" and copy the range based on the selection to refresh for each 8x products and send it to the powerpoint.

Comment: sorry I have been taken away with work in the past days, so I try the proposed code above and It seems to tell me Argument not optional as I had the code linked to a command button - any idea?

Comment: @Guillaume See https://exceloffthegrid.com/assign-macro-with-arguments-to-a-form-control-button/.

Comment: thanks @wizzwizz4 - worked perfectly, appreciate the time and advise :)